# how to loop through associative array and echo out to list?

Tags: php, arrays

I have managed to get my  first array  working but no matter how many code examples I try I cannot step through each array row and echo the three columns / elements out to a

.

The var_dump of my array is:-

```
array(27) { [3]=>  array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(3) "295" ["title"]=>  string(24) "ask.sqlservercentral.com" ["questions"]=>  int(57) } [4]=>  array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(3) "287" ["title"]=>  string(36) "LensFail.com - Photography Questions" ["questions"]=>  int(42) } [2]=>  array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(3) "437" ["title"]=>  string(12) "VideoWTF.com" ["questions"]=>  int(37) } [13]=>  array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(2) "92" ["title"]=>  string(8) "Moms4Mom" ["questions"]=>  int(36) } [9]=>
```

I have tried using this but I did not get the expected results:-

```
foreach($results as $key=>$value)
    {
    echo $key.": ".$value;
    }
```

Can someone please help with a code example that loops through the array and echos ID, Title, Questions to a

Thanks in advance of your help.

Jonathan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($results as $k => $v) {
    echo '<li>' . $v['id'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . $v['title'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . $v['questions'] . '</li>';
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: thank thank you! Apologies I am as a dumb as a donkey and only learning - I get it now!!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having problems is because this is a 2D array. You have to iterate twice. try something like this.

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $key.": ".$value;
    }
}
```